# Apply adjustments to smart object also to healing brush edits

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, smartobject

As an example, suppose I open this image (from a simple PNG or JPG file):

[image]

I convert its only layer to a smart object so I can non-destructively make adjustments, apply filters, etc.

I create a new layer and make some edits with the spot healing brush on that layer (so it's non-destructive as well).

[image]

Then I make some adjustment such as brightness.

[image]

The adjustment is applied to the base image (the smart object) but not to the edits that I made with the healing brush.

What am I doing wrong and how should I do it so that overall changes like brightness apply to edits made with the healing brush, while keeping everything editable and non-destructive?

Comment: Add an adjustment layer above both the smart object layer and the edited layer.

Answer (score 2):

Most often to work non-destructively, one needs to make *global* adjustments first, then any more targets corrections.

The healing tools merely gather what is visible and try to match surrounding pixels. So, you *don't* want to alter surrounding pixels *after* anything such as healing. You'll want to treat the SO and healing layer more as a `Group`.

You *could* merely use an **Adjustment Layer** above the SO and healing layer(s) to alter the brightness. Then adjustments would alter all underlying pixels, not just the SO.